# ngx-Bootstrap 4 dropdown and navbar not working with Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular7, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to add Bootstrap 4 to Angular 7, I see the styles are overridden by bootstrap styles, but navigation bar and dropdown box is not working.

I followed [this document](https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-angular-7-and-bootstrap-4-styling-6011b206080) to add Bootstrap to Angular 7 project.
I have added below code to angular.json

```
 "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
           "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
        ]
```

Here is [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-boostrap4) on I have on stackblitz which is not working

Here is simple jQuery Bootstrap [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstraponly), which works as expected

Comment: you need some package to handle the behavior, look into https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/

Comment: I edited your Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-boostrap4-q2s5zy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html, i added ngx-bootstrap npm package and updated it to use that you can see how https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation#getting-started

Comment: Yes adding ngx-bootstrap it worked, i am trying to get it to work without is since it is not one of approved software where i work.

Answer (score 3):

Some changes needed to [your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-boostrap4-5z5axn?file=src/app/app.component.html) to make it work... added `dropdown`, `dropdownToggle` and `*dropdownMenu`

check the updated/working **app.component.html**:

```
<div class="container">
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>

  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>

    <!-- Dropdown -->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" dropdown>
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown" dropdownToggle>
        Dropdown link
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" *dropdownMenu>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="dropdown" dropdown>
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" dropdownToggle >Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" *dropdownMenu>
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @kulkarni, does this work for you as you intended ?